# <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="data"> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected literal at position 2

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, primeng

Angular9 with PrimeNG calender throws error when used with model. for first time able to select date but on reselection getting error

```
ERROR TypeError: val.getMonth is not a function
```

I fixed by adding a attribute as `dateFormat="mm/dd/yy"`. Let me know any other solutions

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="data" [config]="config" class="customtxtBox" type="date" [id]="config.id" (onSelect)="onValueChange($event)" [showIcon]="true"
        icon="pi pi-calendar" [className]="config.styleClass" [required]="config.required" [yearNavigator]="true" [numberOfMonths]="1"
        dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [monthNavigator]="true" [disabledDays]="[0, 6]" [disabledDates]="disabledDates" yearRange="2000:2030" [minDate]="futureDate" ngDefaultControl></p-calendar>
```

in TS

```
this.data = this.psDateStringAsLDate(this.data);

psDateStringAsLDate(dateOnlyString: string): Date {
    let utcDate: Date = new Date(dateOnlyString);
    return new Date(utcDate.getUTCFullYear(), utcDate.getUTCMonth(), utcDate.getUTCDate(),
      utcDate.getUTCHours(), utcDate.getUTCMinutes(), utcDate.getUTCSeconds(),
      utcDate.getUTCMilliseconds());
  }
```

Comment: add some codes pls!

Comment: @kian it have been done (it's to inform you about this update)